# Audiokit: How to add start/stop-buttons and their functionality within an Audiobus Panel overlay?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, aksequencer, audiobus

When using Audiobus within an AudioKit app that integrates midi sequencer functionality it could a very handy to use the feature of Audiobus that shows start- and stop buttons within its panel overlay, which is also used for hopping between the apps currently running through Audiobus.

How could I integrate these buttons and how could I trigger actions within my AudioKit app?

Thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an ABTrigger, include how you want your transport controls to be handled in the trigger's closure, then add the ABTrigger to your Audiobus controller. You also need to manage/update the trigger state from your project.

I made an example project ([AudiobusMIDISender](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/develop/Examples/iOS/AudiobusMIDISender)) last week that demonstrates this and gives some example code.

But you should definitely read through the Audiobus docs if you want to do anything fancy.

Comment: Thanks for making this example! 